# I cannot quit "distnoted" in my Activity Monitor on my IMAC; it won't let me and I've tried and it's causing major issues and slowing down

Tags: mac

"distnote" on my IMAC is causing my desktop to stall and stick and slowing it down but I cannot go into my Activity Monitor to Force Quit.  It will not allow it and it seems to be cloning itself.  Why can't I stop this?  No matter what I do, I can't seem to get rid of it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Daemons are restarted automatically if they exit/crash/are killed.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111197/runaway-distnoted-process and https://superuser.com/questions/1546441/very-high-cpu-usage-for-distnoted-on-mac